# How to store passwords in Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-button

The `Remember passwords` option in Tor Browser is greyed out.

In past versions of the Tor Browser Bundle there was a setting in Tor Button, but in v3.5 it's no longer there. How can I store passwords in Tor Browser?

Comment: Remember, exit nodes can often read passwords you are sending if you are logging into a non https site. In general its also not best to edit your tor browser, as it can lead to a unique fingerprint for you. I would imagine if you would need to change the firefox back to normal firefox, by deleting it from the tor folder and putting in a new one. however this may not work, and even if it does, it is HIGHLY not recommended. Just write the passwords somewhere else. This isn't something you should be doing.

Comment: No one knows the answer? Am I the only one being disturbed by this? So what do you do? Remember all passwords? Use always the same trivial passwords for unimportant sites? Always copy and paste your passwords?

Comment: Fearing browser fingerprinting is greatly exaggerated here. Only if you change settings, that servers can notice, you change your browser fingerprint. Whether you store passwords using Firefox's local store password mechanism or not, I would wonder if servers can detect this, since it's a local feature.

Comment: @user1055 I understand you want a "straight answer" but, if you're using TOR, you should already kind of understand that maybe you shouldn't be storing passwords in the browser. Anon did not "miss the topic", in fact they have the right idea. Instead of keeping passwords in a place where, if someone were to open up your tor browser, they will NOT ONLY be able to look at the history (because it was enabled), but now they will have automatic password completion...good job. I use the same "generator/expiration" method with a micro, waterproof flash drive encrypted with veracrypt on a quick-releas

Comment: Given that keepass support on Linux is crap and I use FF / tor in the first place for cross platform compatibility, what are the alternatives?

Comment: @user14587 “if you're using TOR, you should already *kind of* understand that *maybe* you shouldn't be storing passwords in the browser” (emphasis added) This is not convincing. And to make things worse, the rest of your comment does not justify the quoted section (other than to say it involves saving history – this is a decision each user should make for themselves).

Answer (score 18):

Go to privacy setting and change the history setting to "remember history" and then "remember passwords for sites" will no longer be greyed out.

Comment: Yes! This is the right answer! I wonder how it's possible that a totally offtopic answer it's the most voted one...

Comment: Note that the option "remember logins" is under the "security" options, not "privacy". (version 7.0.5)

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it does in fact answer the question, but [I have some concerns about this procedure](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22087/does-setting-tor-browser-to-remember-history-cause-tor-browser-to-violate-any).

Comment: This does not work as of Tor Browser v10.5, see [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/22503/32864)

Comment: Does not work..