# Can't set master password in the tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, whonix, browsers

I'm using the tor browser version 10.5.2 in whonix 15, everything works, except that I cannot save logins in the tor browser because every time I try to setup a master password, a popup window appears, throwing me the following message : Unable to change Master Password.

Now I tried several things, which didn't work out :

1. Disabling Tor private browsing mode and setting it to Remember history. (I disabled it via: Preferences > Privacy & Security > History > Tor Browser will > Remember history).
2. Setting security.nocertdb to false (which was set to false by default, so I didn't have to toggle it).
3. Restarted the browser

Any idea on how I might be able set this Master Password ?

PS: I know it's generally a bad idea to store passwords in the embedded password manager of browsers, but this particular browser is isolated in a whonix VM, which can only connect to the .onion site of my email provider. So I won't be searching the internet with this browser or doing anything else than accessing one unique website. That said, I have carefully thought about the reason why I want to do this, so please don't bother advising me otherwise.

Comment: I believe by `tor browser Version 78.11.0esr` you mean `Tor Browser 10.5 (based on Mozilla Firefox 78.11.0esr)`?

Comment: That's correct. Tor 10.5.2

Comment: You are not alone. I have the very same issue. Reinstalling Tor on a Linux Mint device is not helping either.

Comment: This gets better: a previous Tor version on my other PC got auto-updated and silently *removed* all my saved logins and passwords. Looks like Tor developers have been sucked into the modern trend of "assume your user is stupid", which is f*** annoying.

Comment: `While the password manager is not supported in Tor Browser, we don't intentionally break it.` - my bad, I should stop badmouthing people.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug that will be fixed soon, see: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40506

Answer (score 3):

This got fixed as of 10.5.4 (based on Mozilla Firefox 78.13.0esr):

[image]

Source: https://blog.torproject.org/new-release-tor-browser-1054